# Using scripting to open InDesign file and update table data from an excel document that is located in the folder

Tags: excel, scripting, adobe-indesign

My company makes data reports that are often replicated a couple hundred times. I've created a document that has table data attached to an excel file and can be updated through the links panel. My question is, is there a way to update the data in the tables just by running a script, pointing to the excel file within the same folder?

There are more complicated actions that need to be completed in the file, but this would be a great starting point!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, you have the list of names of indd files in Excel and you want a script that will automatically open these indd files, update links inside the indd files, generate PDFs ('data reports'), save and close the indd files. Is it correct description?

Comment: Yup, exactly. I feel like it's gotta be possible. I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that takes list of INDD files (full paths!) from the clipboard opens them, updates links, saves PDFs (in the same folders with the same names as opened documents), saves and closes the INDD files:

```
var settings = save_setting();

var list = get_list_from_cliboard();

while (list.length) {
    var doc = app.open(list.shift());
    update_links(doc);
    save_pdf(doc);
    doc.close(SaveOptions.YES);
}

restore_settings(settings);


// functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

function get_list_from_cliboard() {
    var temp_doc = app.documents.add();
    app.paste();
    try { var contents = temp_doc.pages[0].textFrames[0].parentStory.contents.split('\r') }
    catch(e) { var contents = [] }
    temp_doc.close(SaveOptions.NO);
    return contents;
}

function update_links(doc) {
    var links = doc.links.everyItem().getElements();
    while(links.length) {
        var link = links.pop();
        if (link.status == LinkStatus.LINK_OUT_OF_DATE) link.update();
    }
}

function save_pdf(doc) {
    var name = doc.name.replace(/\.indd/g, '.pdf');
    var file = File(doc.fullName.parent + '/'  + name);
    var preset = app.pdfExportPresets.item("[High Quality Print]");
    app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.PDF_TYPE, file, false, preset);
}

function save_setting() {
    var settings = {
        checkLinksAtOpen: app.linkingPreferences.checkLinksAtOpen,
        viewPDF: app.pdfExportPreferences.viewPDF,
    };
    app.linkingPreferences.checkLinksAtOpen = false;
    app.pdfExportPreferences.viewPDF = false;
    return settings;
}

function restore_settings(settings) {
    app.linkingPreferences.checkLinksAtOpen = settings.checkLinksAtOpen;
    app.pdfExportPreferences.viewPDF = settings.viewPDF;
}
```

You can copy in Excel the list of paths to the INDD files run the script and get the PDF files and updated INDD files.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic! Thank you so much! I'm going to try this out. I'll let you know if I have any questions!

Comment: I hate to ask more questions, because you've been so helpful, but you really seem to know your stuff. Doing it this way, I'd still have to setup all of the ID files first, so it wouldn't save that much time. Would there be a way to batch create the ID files from a list of names? Bonus points if those files could be put into folders with the same name.

Comment: Of course you can create indd files on the fly (this script creates a temporary indd file to get contents of clipboard) but, wait... You said that you already have files and these files have something inside, the linked tables etc. It shouldn't be empty files as far as I can tell. Do you mean to create the new indd files from some template, and then put inside the new file some excel table? In this case it makes no sense to update links.

Comment: So, I have a template made, with data tables attached. My thought is, if I export the data as a generic name (data.xlsx) and place it into the folder, the table in the ID file will point to the excel file with a relative path and update. I'm thinking that I might be able to use data merge to create all of the new ID files with the names of the reports filled in and then use your script to update the data and make the PDFs.

Comment: Well so what exactly you have at the start? Template? (It wouldn't hurt to show how the template looks like). Folders? Subfolders? Excel tables? (How their names look like? Do you have a list of the names/paths? Do you put the excel tables into the folders/subdolders manually?) This script takes the list from clipboard but it can scan any folder and search for subfolders as well. As for the Data Merging, it depends. DM means to fill one page with values from one row of source data table. If you want to fill a table via DM the values of the table should be lined in one row, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's very much appreciated! Unfortunately, I can't share the files because of the nature of our business. But, I think I've figured out what I can do. I think I'm going to use a combination of data merge and the script you've given me to update the links and create new files. The only thing I can't figure out is updating the data in the graphs automatically. But, I am trying to work with the 3rd party plugin developer to figure that out. Thank you so much for all of your input! I'm new to this platform, is there anything I can do to rate/award your help?

Comment: Good luck then. Let me know if you need any help again. You can to upvote my answer(s) when you gain more reputation, if you want. But it's not necessary. I'm fine.

Comment: Hi Yuri! Everything you gave me works great! But, I'm running into a new issue. As I said, when I'm creating the files, I'm starting from a template and using data merge to update the naming conventions throughout the report. I'm then running a script that exports all of those files as individual InDesign files. After that, I'm running a script that takes all of those new files and creates folders with the same name and then places the files in the folder. I can then use the script that you gave me to open the files, update the links, and then exports PDFs (Works great by the way, thanks!)...

Comment: ... The problem that I'm running into now is after moving all of the files and folders around, the new InDesign files cant find the link to the Excel and Illustrator files to relink them. Kind of defeats the purpose of all of the automation if I have to manually relink the files. So, my question is, is there a script that I can run to have the file automatically search the folder it's in to find the missing links? The links can be the same name as the original if that helps. Would be cool if it could just find links of the same file type and reconnect. Bonus points if it could be a modified...

Comment: ... version of the script you already gave me to update the links and export the PDF. Again thank you so much for all the help you've already given me. It's very much appreciated!

Comment: Update. I found if I go to the links panel, hit the menu fly-out, and go to utilities -> Search for missing links, it searches in the folder of the file. Any way to script that call out?

Comment: Hi, Steven. I'll try to figure it out this evening. You can call more or less any menu/panel command with a line like: `app.menuActions.itemByName('ID$\***').invoke();` where `***` is a menu/panel command. In your case it probably will be `app.menuActions.itemByName('ID$\Search for Missing Links').invoke();` And make sure the panel 'Links' is visible, otherwise it won't work. You can make the panel visible from the script as well with the line: `app.panels.itemByName('$ID/Links').visible = true;` See the details here: http://kasyan.ho.ua/tips/indesign_script/all/open_menu_item.html

Comment: Have you tried to implement the 'menuActions'? Do you still need a help?

Comment: I tried to add it to the code that you gave me to update the links and export the PDFs, but I couldn't get it to work. My javascript is awful. What lines do I need to replace?

Comment: I suppose you could add the line somewhere right after you open an indd file. In my code it would be between the lines `var doc = app.open(list.shift());` and `update_links(doc);
`

Comment: Hi Yuri! I tried this today:

`while (list.length) {
    var doc = app.open(list.shift());
    app.panels.itemByName('$ID/Links').visible = true;
    app.menuActions.itemByID(132634).invoke();
    update_links(doc);
    save_pdf(doc);
    doc.close(SaveOptions.YES);
}`

(Sorry, I can't figure out how to do a code block in the comments)

But I keep getting an error code that says: Action is not enabled. I tried to add the script to open the links menu, but I'm afraid I'm not doing it correctly.

Sorry if I'm annoying at this point. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: 'Action is not enabled' means that either the panel is hidden (you can open the panel manually after all) or the menu item is grayed by some reason. I tried to reproduce the problem and failed to get the error. The line `app.menuActions.itemByID(132634).invoke();` works fine for me. I suppose it depends on how exactly your indd files, linked files and folders are placed. If the menu item is not greyed and you're able to perform the command manually the line should work. Additionally you can try to make InDesign to find missing link automatically this way: https://imgur.com/h0c6NDj

Comment: I'm sorry if I failed to help. The task a whole looks quite simply. I'm sure it can be done via a script without the menu actions. But it hard to guess out without the files and folders. If you remove the sensitive information from your files I could to try to solve the mystery.

Comment: Hi Yuri. Thank you again for all of the help. It appears that there is a difference between find missing links and search for missing links. As far as showing the files, is there a way that I can privately message them to you? Or I can zoom with you or something to show you the work flow. I don't know if that's against the rules of the platform, but it might eliminate a lot of back and forth. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically it can be something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// get the destination table 
// (a first table from the first text frame of the first page)
var table = doc.pages[0].textFrames[0].parentStory.tables[0];

// get the xls file
var xls_file = new File(doc.fullName.parent + '/table.xls');
// xls_file = xls_file.openDlg(); // <-- use it if you want the dialog window
if (!xls_file) exit();

// create a new text frame and put the contents of the xls file into it
var data_frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames.add();
data_frame.place(xls_file);

// convert the contents of the 'xls' frame into a 2D array 'data'
var data = [];
var data_text = data_frame.parentStory.tables[0].convertToText();
var paragraphs = data_text.contents.split('\r');
while (paragraphs.length) data.push(paragraphs.shift().split('\t'));

// remove the 'xls' frame
data_frame.remove();

// fill the destination table with contents of the 2D array
var rows = Math.min(table.rows.length, data.length);
var cols = Math.min(table.rows[0].cells.length, data[0].length);
for (var r=0; r<rows; r++) for (var c=0; c<cols; c++) {
    table.rows[r].cells[c].contents = data[r][c];
}
```

Input (the source table in Excel, and the destination table in InDesign):

[image]

Output (the table in InDesign):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. But, this is even more complicated than what I need. Basically, I just need to run a script that opens the InDesign file in the folder and then update the link to the excel file within the same folder. It's already linked to the excel file, I just need it to update. I also can't figure out how to run a script from the root folder to open the file. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Whenever you open an indd file InDesign checks all the links inside the file and if some of the links were changed it asks if these links should be updated or not. All you need is just open the indd file and click 'Yes' in the dialog window.

Comment: Yes. This is just the first step in a problem I am trying to figure out. We make batches of up to 300 reports. I'm trying to figure out a way to create an automation to create all of these reports in one go, without having to open each report one at a time.

Comment: So you want to open an indd file, update the links inside, save and close, and repeat this for hundred another indd files? It can be done pretty easy. But it will need a some list of the indd files. Do you have the list? It can be a table or a txt file for exampe. Or the script can search for all indd files in some folder. Etc. You have to decide how the script will get the list of indd files. (If I understand the task right)

Comment: Yup, we have an Excel Doc with the list of names. We actually have a vLookup made within Excel with all of the data. Right now, the data in the tables are connected to the vLookup and can get updated by selecting the name in the dropdown and saving the file. There are also graphs built in the report that are built in an Illustrator plugin called Datylon that is also linked to the same excel file. There are cross-references built into the ID file that update the naming throughout the report...

Comment: ...The ideal situation and my end goal, is to be able to run through each instance in the dropdown from the vLookup and create a report, without having to open, save, and update each file. I know there's gotta be a way to do this, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start.